# Comparing object columns row wise | Error -ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, pandas, compare

I am comparing values in 2 columns using df['Col1']==df['Col2'] and getting the following value error-ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

To replicate the code-

if(df['Col1']==df['Col2']):
print(df.index[df['Col1']])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing two entire columns but it looks like you want the values of any row that has a mismatch.  Have Pandas compare the values in col1 and col2 for all rows, and use that comparison to filter the df to only the rows that mismatch.  Then you can get the index values for the mismatched rows.  Or you could create a 3rd column and get all the values of the 3rd column if there was a mismatch.  See this toy example.

```
row1list = ['a', 'a']
row2list = ['b', 'c']
row3list = ['c', 'd']
df = pd.DataFrame([row1list, row2list, row3list], columns=['Col1', 'Col2'])

df_mismatches = df[df['Col1'] != df['Col2']]

df_mismatches = df_mismatches.reset_index()   # can put index into its own column if you want

print(df_mismatches)
#    index Col1 Col2
# 0      1    b    c
# 1      2    c    d
```

Comment: this approach works for me- however, I'm trying to have 2 conditions in df_mismatches = df[df['Col1'] != df['Col2']], which brings me back to the value error The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Comment: What 2 conditions are you trying to have?  There are ways to test for multiple things at once.  If you use the df[df[col] ... syntax, it compares row by row instead of comparing entire column series, e.g.,  df_mismatches_with_d = df[(df['Col1'] != df['Col2']) & (df['Col2'] == 'd')]